# Issue when getting array element from object in php

Tags: php

The array is encapsulated with an Object..

When I do `var_dump`, this is the structure if object

```
object(stdClass)#57 (1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

When I do `print_r` below is the o/p

```
stdClass Object ( [string] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 ) )
```

Please tell me how can access 1 and 3 from this object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$my_result_array = object(stdClass)#57 (1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "3" } } ;
echo $my_result_array->string[0];
echo $my_result_array->string[1];
```

or you can try like

```
$res = $my_result_array->string;
echo $res[0];
echo $res[1];
```

Comment: I will do that... When I try accepting it says only after 12 mins I can accept any answer